# FunctionDomain in the Reals numbers

Tags: number-theory

Why don't I obtain that $x$ belongs to the `Reals`?

```
FunctionDomain[x^2 + 4, x]
(* Out: True *)

FunctionDomain[x^2 + 4, x, Reals]
(* Out: True *)
```

However, there is no problem here:

```
FunctionDomain[Log[x]/Sqrt[x + y], x]
(* Out: x > 0 && x + y > 0 *)
```

Comment: `True` its mean in this case `x \[Element] Interval[{-Infinity, Infinity}]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FunctionDomain` tells you quantitatively what the domain is:

```
FunctionDomain[Sqrt[x], x]
(* x >= 0 *)
```

`True` just means "no limits" here.